# Can i use the facebook api to get details about who posted on my facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As the title mentions, i wish to make a feed on a website, with the message a user posted on my facebook page and also his name and profile picture.

I managed to get the messages from my fb page but that's about all

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "message": "message",
     "created_time": "time",
     "id": "id"
  },
  {
     "message": "message",
     "created_time": "time",
     "id": "id"
  }
]
}
```

I have been struggling with this for some time now, is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the fields you want (see [the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fields)), in your case, the `from` field (see [post node reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post)).

Comment: Yes, i found that after i asked the question :-) Thanks !